# Does adding an object to a vector store the address of that object?

Tags: c++, vector

For example, I have class Example() in a header file (c++).

main:

```cpp
vector <Example*> memAddress;
Example defaultVariable;
memAddress.push_back(defaultVariable);
```

Even though the vector is initialized as a list of Example pointers, it looks as if it is legal to add an Example object to it. Is it adding the memory address of defaultVariable, or something else entirely?

Comment: That code won't compile. To get the address of your object, it would have to be `memAddress.push_back(&defaultVariable)`. While the language allows you to do that, that pointer will point to garbage once `defaultVariable` gets out of scope... But until that happens, it's valid.

Comment: @AlexG: Certainly some (strange, and probably unwise) type `Example` could make that work.